# What freeware frameworks and tools to choose if I want to build a game like Farmville or Club Penguin?

Tags: multiplayer, open-source, server

Say I like to experiment with multiplayer games and I do not want to reinvent the wheel and build yet another game server. I don’t mind configuring and writing wrappers and adapters (both in c++ and java) for the server.
What server does Farmville use? Is it Java or C based? 
What isometric flash engine do they use?  What other examples can I look into to learn the subject?
Thanks.

Comment: I really do not see why this is a CW question.

Comment: I converted it because it's basically asking for a list of software packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your best bets is to look at [SmartFoxServer Lite](http://www.gotoandplay.it/_articles/multiplayerCentral/).  It's free, but better packages cost money.  It's basically a socket server that uses JSON for all its communication and works well with various clients.

(I haven't used it myself, but heard it recommended in the past.)

Comment: does red5 can do what smartfox can do?

Comment: Definitely check out SmartFoxServer.  It's what Club Penguin is/was based on originally I believe.

Answer (score 2):

For your database needs, I'd highly recommend looking into [Membase](http://www.membase.org/).

> Membase is the primary database for the popular FarmVille and Café World applications at Zynga; and it provides a shared data management platform for NHN, Korea’s largest web application operator with nearly 70 million unique users. - Membase Website

The engine Zynga uses to build FarmVille is highly custom, but [this website](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/02/23/11-flash-isometric-engines-you-can-use-in-your-games/) links to various isometric flash engines and frameworks you may want to look in to.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a useful link which gives some insights: [How FarmVille Scales to Harvest 75 Million Players a Month](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/2/8/how-farmville-scales-to-harvest-75-million-players-a-month.html) (also mind the related articles)